# Custom popup activity in android instead of dialogue

Tags: android, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers, popupwindow

I am making an app that uses maps api, and I want to create a custom popup activity when the user creates a marker (not the generic yes/no dialogue). What I want to do is:

1. when a user longclicks on map it opens a new activity instead of dialogue
2. this activity displays lat and lang, has a field to enter text, and yes/no buttons
3. if a user clicks yes the marker is pinned if no it is not
4. when a user clicks on the created marker it displays lat,lng and the entered text

My current code:

```
    //Add marker on long click
    mMap.setOnMapLongClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnMapLongClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onMapLongClick(LatLng arg0) {

        Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), CreateRestautantActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);

        marker = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.custom_marker))
                .position(
                        new LatLng(arg0.latitude,
                                arg0.longitude))
                .visible(true));

      }
    });
```

Any help is appreciated :)

Comment: why not you are using custom dialogue rather opening activity , if you create separate activity for that map reloads again when you come back again map !! so i would suggest custom dialogue better than this.

Comment: @Jhaman Das I plan to expand this popup - add a date/time option, tag some friends, enable chat, etc, so i thought it would be better to do this as an activity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, maybe I didn't got all the details, but in such case I'd do the following:
**1.** Use `OnMapLongClickListener`. Then in `onMapLongClick()` you can do whatever you want. You have `LatLng` object with `latitude` and `longitude` - you can put them in a `Bundle` or pass them in other way to new `Activity`.
You can refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2091465/how-do-i-pass-data-between-activities-on-android) post for example.
Create a `Marker` and store it as a field in your `Activity`.
**2.** It's easy, I suppose, to make `xml` for new `Activity` and use it at `setContentView()`. Take your arguments passed in previous step and put them in `lat` and `lng` fields. Put `OnClickListener` on your buttons.
**3.** You can start your new `Activity` with [`StartActivityForResult`](http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/reference/android/app/Activity.html#startActivityForResult%28android.content.Intent,%20int%29) method and handle results from your new `Activity` on return.
There is also a lot of information about that on stackoverflow. [For example this.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10407159/how-to-manage-startactivityforresult-on-android) 
Then, in `onActivityResult()` you can make some actions to your `Marker` (remove it, for example). 
**4.** Use [OnMarkerClickListener](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/GoogleMap.OnMarkerClickListener) - and in `onMarkerClick(Marker marker)` from that `Marker` you can call `getPosition()` - and take `lat` and `lng` from it.

If you need more details, let me know ;)

Comment: This looks like the thing I was looking for, thank you for this. I have added my current code in my question. It is what I did before asking this question. I am a beginner in software development so it is not a lot. I will let you know if I get stuck. Thanks again :)

Comment: U welcome ;) Also please consider for future using fragment (or DialogFragment, as @nasch mentioned). It can be complicated as much as you need. It may be difficult for the first time to use it, but using Fragments instead of Activities finally gives your application more flexibility.

Comment: But for first time, it will be good also to make it with Activity )

Comment: I will likely do that. As I said I was afraid to use it because I would call another dialog from it with my contacts list. But as you said, since it can be complex I can use it anyways. I guess that's why I haven't found any examples for activity :)

Answer (score 1):

You should use a `DialogFragment`.  This allows you to customize the appearance and functionality of a dialog.

Android blog post on how to use them: http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2012/05/using-dialogfragments.html

Reference: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DialogFragment.html

Several other tutorials/examples: https://www.google.com/search?q=dialogfragment

Comment: I didn't want to use the dialogue because I plan to make this popup a lot more complex - add a date/time option, tag some friends (from a popup dialogue), enable chat, etc, so i thought it would be better to do this as an activity.

Comment: Anything you can do in an activity you can do in a `DialogFragment`.  I think this will be a lot simpler than trying to manage navigation between two activities.

Comment: My biggest concern was that I would have to open contacts dialogue from DialogueFragment (when I add an option to select the friends to tag on a marker). It seemed like something that should not be done. Thanks for the explanation, it really helps :)